# Dynamodb Not Triggering

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I created a dynamodb table and associated a lambda function  which will be triggered on every write

but then I wrote 20 fields but the lambda was triggered only twice

is AWS Lambda incapable of handling 20 invocations? What is wrong here?

Comment: The Lambda function will receive a list of events in each invocation. Are you sure the function didn't receive all 20 as a list? Are you updating different records each time? It sounds like you only updated 20 fields on the same record?

Comment: I'm sure, I have a table of users  where the "userid" is the primary key and each record has some details and all that stuff

Anytime the details are changed, it triggers a lambda function that writes certain values from the changed record to another table

I change 20 records in the table nd I get only 2 writes in the new table, There are no data on cloudwatch too

Comment: Observing 2 writes in the new table is not a guarantee that 20 events were not generated. Show us your Lambda function code, at least the skeleton that handles the events. All 20 events could have been streamed to you in 2 Lambda invocations.

Comment: Mr. Jarmod, You were Spot ON!!

I did not account for the multiple events, my bad, Thanks a million for pointing out

Thanks a lot for both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda polls Dynamodbstream in a fixed time interval and triggers your Lambda function by passing all the records as a list in one lambda call. You can however control the max size using batchSize while creating your lambda function.

Here is the sample node.js call to iterate over list of records

```
exports.lambda_handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
        console.log(record.eventID);
        console.log(record.eventName);
        console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
    });
    callback(null, "message"); 
};
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-create-package.html for sample code in other languages